# Convert a string into a char array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

New to C++ and So here is part of a project I'm working on, taking a string and printing the most commonly used number along with how many times it was used. i thought this was right, but for some reason my char array wont be read in. any tips or suggestions on how to fix?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char getMostFreqLetter(string ss);

int main() {
    string s; //initilizing a variable for string s
    s = ("What is the most common letter in this string "); // giving s a string

    getMostFreqLetter(s); // caling the function to print out the most freq Letter

    return 0;
}

char getMostFreqLetter(string ss) {
    int max, index, i = 0;
    int array[255] = {0};
    char letters[];

    // convert all letters to lowercase to make counting letters non case sensative
    for (int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i ++){
        ss[i] = tolower(ss[i]);
    }

    //read each letter into
    for (int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i ++){
        ++array[letters[i]];
    }
    //

    max = array[0];
    index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i ++){
        if( array[i] > max)
        {
            max = array[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you considering whitespace as most frequent letter too ?

Comment: Please turn up your warning level on your compiler. You should get something like `error: storage size of 'letters' isn't known` for `char letters[];`.

Comment: I would honestly just use the string you pass into ss, a string can be accessed like an array using the `[]` operator. If this is for some kind of learning exercise then changing `char letters[]` to `char letters[ss.size()]` which should in this case, fix your issue.

Comment: Well we don't have to do it any specific way, just from reading my book tho, this looked like the best way of trying to do it!

Comment: But i used ss.size() into char letters[ss.size()] but for some reason, it still wont print out my most freq letter, or the number of times. My for loops look fine right? i can't seem to find anything wrong with them

Comment: I've just run the code with @gowrath s edits and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not considering white space as letter.

Then more efficient way could have been

```
vector<int> count(26,0);
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    int range = to_lower(s[i])-'a';
    if ( range >= 0 && range < 26)
        count[range]++;
}

// Now you can do fix the max while iterating over count;
```

Comment: Isn't that gonna go out of bounds?

Comment: gowrath : I don't think so. Please explain, where it's going to fail.

Comment: if s[i] is a space, the ascii value is 32. You'll try accessing count[32-97] no?

Answer (score 0):

Use [string::c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).
It converts a string to a character array.

Comment: The question doesn't have a good title but it's not really asking for a specific function to convert a string to a char array.

Answer (score -1):

You have a few errors in your code.

Firstly, the array of chars `letters` is completely unused. You should disregard it and iterate over the string `ss` instead which is what I think you intended to do.

This would change your second for loop from `++array[letters[i]];` to  `++array[ss[i]];`.

Secondly, your last for loop is buggy. You are using i as the index to look for the frequency in array whereas you need to use the ascii value of the character (ss[i]) instead. Here is a fixed version with comments:

```
    index = ss[0];
    max = array[index];
    for (int i = 0; i < ss.length(); i ++){
        if(!isspace(ss[i]) && array[ss[i]] > max)
        {
            max = array[ss[i]];   // you intended to use the ascii values of the characters in s to mark their place in array. In you code, you use i which is the just the index of the character in s as opposed to the ascii value of that character. Hence you need to use array[ss[i]].
            index = ss[i];

        }
    }
    return index;
```

Once you make the above changes you get the following output when run on your string:

```
Most freq character: t
```

Comment: I've not downvoted but the extra brace was after the getMostFreqLetter() function and I guess this "Firstly, you need to initialise the array letters with some size such as char letters[100] or whatever appropriate number you need. Actually, tbh you aren't using letters at all. Just replace it with ss instead." isn't overly descriptive. Though these are only nitpicks and I tend to agree with this answer.

Comment: @George Thanks for the input. Actually there are bigger errors in this code than I initially thought; fixed above.

Comment: After looking at the op's question a bit more, this is a good answer, upvoted!